# Getting NullPointerException while using PrinterJob

Tags: java, printing, javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to print receipts through a JavaFX application but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` whenever I try to print.

```
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
// More Imports

public class PrintBasket 
{
    public PrintBasket()
    {
        VBox vboxPages = new VBox();
        // Some Code
        printAction();
    }

    public void printAction()
    { 
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        // Some Code

        if(printerJob.printPage(vboxPages)) { // Getting exception at this line
              printerJob.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception I'm getting is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Dialogs.PrintBasket.printAction(PrintBasket.java:638)
    at Dialogs.PrintBasket.<init>(PrintBasket.java:214)
    at Tabs.PrintUtil.<init>(PrintUtil.java:75)
```

My Java is version 8 and my OS is Ubuntu 14.04.01

Comment: From the [JavaDocs for `PrinterJob.createPrinterJob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html#createPrinterJob--) *"If there are no printers available, this will return null. Some platforms may provide a pseudo printer, which creates a document. These will be enumerated here so long as the platform also enumerates them as if they are printers"*

Comment: @KevinEsche That was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, since I don't have any printers connected, it is returning null. Will installing a PDF converter driver do the trick?

Comment: @bilesh.g I would say it's a good bet that you're getting a `null` from `PrinterJob.createPrinterJob` because you have no printers install.  Installing a PDF converter "might" work, but, as the documentation says, it will depend on how the platform treats it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok. I'll check if it works.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Installed Cups and the code is not giving any exception now. Thank you for the advice. :)

Comment: You might consider adding you own answer with how you fixed it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sure, will do that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the JavaDocs for PrinterJob.createPrinterJob "If there are no
>   printers available, this will return null. Some platforms may provide
>   a pseudo printer, which creates a document. These will be enumerated
>   here so long as the platform also enumerates them as if they are
>   printers"

As indicated by **@MadProgrammer** in the above comment, I didn't have any printers installed and that is why I was getting a `NullPointerException`. So, I went ahead and installed `cups-pdf`.

I installed `cups-pdf` as follows -

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

And then created a PDF printer using which I was able to print the receipts (Source: [Way to Create PDF Printer in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/04/easy-way-to-create-pdf-printer-in-ubuntu-12-04.html)). Now, I'm not getting any `NullPointerException` while printing.